# How do I exit coqtop REPL?

Tags: coq

I am using the `coqtop` REPL because I don't want to use the coqide. But how do I exit the REPL? I have tried a lot of different ways but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exit using `Quit.` or `Ctrl-D`. I am afraid it is not documented anywhere at least not somewhere it could be found easily. Issue raised [here](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/16507).

Answer (score 1):

Type "ctrl-D" on the keyboard.